# TFS: no longer auto-checking out files I change from within VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

Has this happened to anyone? Nothing has changed on my system, yet TFS no longer will auto-checkout files for me when I edit them. If it has, what did you do to fix it?

Under *Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment*, both Saving and Editing are set to "Check out automatically", so I'm pretty confused at this point.

Comment: It hasn't gone offline has it? right click on the solution and in the source control section choose "go online"

Comment: I have a sinking feeling in my stomach that might be the problem. I have lost my VPN connection a few times today. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @grenade, that turned out to be the problem, if you post it as an answer I'll mark it as an answer for you. I'd hate to see you not get the rep for helping me solve this.

Comment: See my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837803/tee-2012-does-not-check-out-files-automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did end up having to "go online" for my solution. What a pain.

Comment: Had this happen on VS2012 and the UI does not make this exceptionally clear. Gosh how many times have I restart VS and the OS...

Answer (score 1):

if you restart VS does it fix it? I get it sometimes too, but it's just fouled up VS

Comment: Yeah, I've restarted both VS and my system. So weird. I'll give it another try, though, couldn't hurt!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your specific TFS or Visual Studio version, however in VS2010 you have:

File > Source Control > Change Source Control

[image]

If your Solution/Project is listed like above with no Server Name, Binding etc., select it and click Bind. That may get things going again