# TEE 2012 does not check out files automatically

Tags: eclipse, team-explorer-everywhere

I have TFS Server 2012 SP1.
Eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios Service Release 2).
TEE 11.0.0.201211191425

I see a complete team menu, I can check-out and check-in files manually.
However if I just start editing a file it will not be checked out automatically :( as it did with 2010 before updates.

I have tried to change settings to "Display progress while checking out" and "Prompt before checking out" - no effect.

"Detect changes..." functionality does not work either.

Only if I close the project and then open it again, the modified file will be checked out automatically (only once).

**wtf???**

**UPDATE:**
The modified file will be checked out automatically also if I manually check-out/check-in another file in the same project.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem found**

If Visual Studio 2012 is opened on the same PC and connected to the same TFS server, the TEE behaves as described above :(

@Edward Thomson, I think it is a bug. TEE should at least have displayed an error messages.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, indeed, but I'm having trouble reproducing it.  Do the pending changes show in VS when you have both open?  If you refresh the pending changes view do they show?

Comment: @Edward, It turned out to be even more complex than I initially thought. Yesterday I had the same issue with Visual Studio closed. Unfortunately, now I have to switch to more urgent tasks but I will continue testing TFS2012 maybe next week or already in January. Anyway I'll post here as soon as I have more info.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your specific TFS or Visual Studio version, however in VS2010 you have:

File > Source Control > Change Source Control

[image]

If your Solution/Project is listed like above with no Server Name, Binding etc., select it and click Bind.  That may get things going again